# RequireJS: Dynamic dependencies within nested require of a module

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Suppose there is a function that returns an array containing dynamic dependencies.
Then within a module B these dependencies are used. Another module A in turn uses module B.

A.js

```
define([B], function(moduleB){
    moduleB.m();
})
```

B.js:

```
define([ dep1, dep2 ], function( dep1, dep2 ) {

    var dyndeps = dep2.getDynDeps();
    var moduleB = {}

    require(dyndeps, function() {
        moduleB.m = function() { ... };
    })

    return moduleB;

});
```

The problem with this approach is, that the inner require is executed asynchronously, so the method m is not available in time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `B.m` is provided by a dynamic dependency, `B` should provide an interface for waiting on it to become available. There are a number of [plugins](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Plugins#script-helpers) to allow that, e.g. **[rq](https://github.com/asengupta/requirejs-q)** (using Q promises), **[promise](https://github.com/jokeyrhyme/requirejs-promise)** (using jquery, Q, RSVP or ES6 promises), **[promiseme](https://github.com/andreineculau/requirejs-promiseme)** (self-contained?).

Using one of those, `B` would not return `moduleB`, but a promise. The nested `require` call would resolve the promise with complete `moduleB`. `A` would require `<PLUGIN>!B`. E.g. using `promise` and `jquery`:

```js
// A.js
define(["promise!B"], function(moduleB){
    // B is complete now
    moduleB.m();
})

// B.js
define([ "dep1", "dep2", "jquery" ], function( dep1, dep2, $ ) {

    var dyndeps = dep2.getDynDeps();
    var moduleB = {};
    var loaded = new $.Deferred();

    require(dyndeps, function() {
        moduleB.m = function() { ... };
        loaded.resolve(moduleB);
    })

    return loaded.promise();    
});
```

The only remaining problem with this approach is that the client code (`A.js`) needs to know to depend on `B` in a special way. A better solution would be to have `B` hide its dynamic nature like:

```
// A.js
define(["B"], function(moduleB){
    moduleB.m();
})

// B.js
define([ "promise!dynamicB" ], function( moduleB ) {
    return moduleB;
});

// still inside B.js define a "private" named module:
define("dynamicB", ["dep1", "dep2", "jquery"], function() {
    var dyndeps = dep2.getDynDeps();
    var loaded = new $.Deferred();
    var moduleB = {};

    require(dyndeps, function() {
        moduleB.m = function() { ... };
        loaded.resolve(moduleB);
    })

    return loaded.promise();    
});
```

Now `B` can be used just as any other module.